# How to find operator norm?

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory

Here is the question I am looking at:

Define $T_{\cos x}(f): L^2(-\pi,\pi)\rightarrow L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ by $T_{\cos x}(f)=\langle f, \cos x\rangle \cos x$.

a) Use Parseval's Identity $\langle f,g\rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx$ to find $T_{\cos x}(f)$ for the function $f(x)=x$.

b) Now find $T_{\cos x}(g)$ for $g(x)=x^2$.

c) Determine the operator norm $\lVert T_{\cos x} \rVert$ and show $\lVert T_{\cos x}(x^2) \rVert \leq \lVert T_{\cos x} \rVert \cdot \lVert x^2 \rVert$.

Here is what I have done so far and where I am having trouble. For part (a), what does the bar over $g(x)$ mean in the integral? I kind of ignored it and found $T_{\cos x}(x)=\langle x, \cos x\rangle \cos x$ and $\langle x, \cos x \rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x\cos x \,dx$ which equals $0$ so $T_{\cos x}(x)= 0\cdot \cos x = 0$.

For part (b), I similarly ignored the bar over $g(x)$ and found $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^2\cos x \,dx=-2$ so $T_{\cos x}(x^2)=-2\cos x$. Is my reasoning correct for these two parts?

For part (c), I am struggling to find the operator norm $\lVert T_{\cos x} \rVert$. I have that it should be $\frac{1}{2}$, but I can't figure out how to get there. If I understood this part of the question, I could do the rest of part (c) on my own. Would anyone be willing to help me with this? My book has the following definition: $\lVert T \rVert=\sup \{\lVert Tf \rVert_K\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bar is the complex conjugate. You could ignore it in what you did because $g$ was real valued.

As for the norm of $T$, this is easier seen in the abstract case. You have $T:H\to H$ with $H$ a Hilbert space, and $Tw=\langle w,v\rangle\,v$ for a fixed $v\in H$. You have
$$
\|Tw\|=\|\langle w,v\rangle\,v\|=|\langle w,v\rangle|\,\|v\|\leq\|w\|\,\|v\|^2.
$$
The inequality is sharp, as can be seen from taking $w=v$. Thus $\|T\|=\|v\|^2$. In your case,
$$
\|T\|=\|v\|^2=\frac1{2\pi}\,\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos^2x\,dx=\frac12.
$$

Comment: Please upvote if you found the answer useful